# Redirect to http://mydomain.com rather than http://www.mydomain.com

Tags: dns, web-development

I created a website and I would like when I put any link pointing to my website, the "www" to be removed.

For example when someone enters `http://www.mydomain.com/users` into the browser address, this to be changed into `http://mydomain.com/users` when the page loads up.

I have seen this happening with twitter. if you try to go to `http://www.twitter.com/john` it will automatically remove the "www" and change the address to `http://twitter.com/john` .

However, this does not happen for `http://www.facebook.com/john`.

I am not sure if this have something to do with the domain's configuration (CNAME record?) but any point / tip to the right direction will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple HTTP redirect to remove the "www". Twitter for example uses a `HTTP 302 (Moved temporarily)` redirect to point `http://www.twitter.com` to `http://twitter.com` (and then a `HTTP 301 (Moved permanently)` to redirect to `https://twitter.com`).

Depending on your web server, there should be configuration options for this. In Apache, for example, you'd add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that has to be configured in your host.

If you are using Apache for example you could add a couple of lines to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```